# Bind an existing process to a socket

Tags: process, socket, file-descriptors

I want to bind an existing process to a socket listenning on a specific port with `nc` and send input to it (a python interactive shell, an editor...) whatever process, just send a pid and bind it, since file descriptors are meaningless for another process rather than the existing process and can't use `/proc/<pid>/fd/0` to send input to process (the `fds` are just symlinks to a terminal).

The last statement is too conclusive to be true since `strace -p<pid> -s9999 -e write` can spy STDIN and STDOUT (don't know how)of a process but that's something I will investigate later, from now I want to bind an existing process to a socket and send data to it via a socket.

Comment: “The last statement is too conclusive to be true” — nice... Why repeat a statement if you don’t believe it then?

Comment: let's say nano is pid 18541 and I want to send its input over a socket. I have a listening nc on port 5555 and type `/proc/18541/fd/0 > /dev/tcp/localhost/5555` I got `bash: /proc/18541/fd/0: Permission denied` even though I'm root

Comment: I have been able to send data to another process with `gdb -p <pid>` with `call write(0,"test",4)` but I want to bind the process to a port and send data through it (it doesn't matter if I get the stdout or the process in question does, those are details I don't want to delve into right now, just the input is what interests me)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use taskset, you can use `taskset -p -c`, you can refer to this post [Taskset example](https://www.glennklockwood.com/hpc-howtos/process-affinity.html#31-the-linux-portable-way-taskset)

`If your process is already running, you can define thread affinity while in flight. It also lets you bind specific TIDs to specific processors at a level of granularity greater than specifying -c 0,2,4,6 because Linux may still schedule two threads on core2 and nothing on core0.`